# can't install puma gem, using with Heroku and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

Heroku recently recommended using the puma webserver gem rather than unicorn.  So, I removed the unicorn gem and installed the puma gem.  It installs to the `Gemfile`, but not the `Gemfile.lock`.  I have no clue what's going on.  Here's the code and the steps I've taken.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'puma', '~> 2.11.0' - in the production group
```

After running `bundle install`, running `gem list` shows (among others):

```
psych (2.0.5)
puma (2.11.0)
pundit (0.3.0)
rack (1.6.0)
```

But it's not in the `Gemfile.lock`:

```
pg (0.18.1)
pry (0.10.1)
  coderay (~> 1.1.0)
  method_source (~> 0.8.1)
  slop (~> 3.4)
pundit (0.3.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
rack (1.6.0)
```

Running foreman confirms that.  From the command line, `foreman start`:

```
19:58:11 web.1  | started with pid 51379
19:58:12 web.1  | /Users/dougharman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/
  bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:256:in `block in replace_gem': 
  puma is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
19:58:12 web.1  |   from /Users/dougharman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/puma:22:in `<main>'
19:58:12 web.1  |   from /Users/dougharman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
19:58:12 web.1  |   from /Users/dougharman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
19:58:12 web.1  | exited with code 1
19:58:12 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

There are several SO questions dealing with similar problems running Windows.  I'm on Mac OSX Mavericks, ruby 2.1.5, and rails 4.2.0.  Based upon some of the SO q&a, I uninstalled rvm and ruby (including all prior versions) and reinstalled them.  I am still getting the same outcome.
Any ideas are welcome.  Coincidentally, I tried reinstalling unicorn and wasn't able to do so.  I've only touched the other files mentioned in the Heroku article [Deploying Rails Applications with the Puma Web Server](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server) 
The deploy was previously working using unicorn.  Thank you in advance for your suggestions.  I'm out of ideas and otherwise dead in the water until the Chicago Ruby North Shore MeetUp this weekend!

Comment: you said running foreman start proves that but you set the gem to only run in the production group.  remove the group for a second, run bundle again and do foreman start.

Comment: Anthony - Please make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.  I removed the Puma and Foreman gems from the production group - putting them in the 'unassigned' list - and running bundle install added puma to the Gemfile.lock  Foreman is now running.  The other gem I added, per Heroku's instructions was Rack-Timeout, which had the same issue as puma until i removed it from the production group.  Everything is now working.  Thank you!  And again, please make this an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, gems that are part of the production group won't run in development (unless you purposely run a production environment locally)

If you truly want to run Puma in development (which I recommend), remove it from the production group in your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install` again.

so this:

```
group :production do
  gem 'puma'
end
```

becomes just:

```
gem 'puma'
```